# Как правильно присвоить переменной значение?

Tags: c#

Всем привет, у меня такая задача вывести на экран текущую дату, я пытался сделать так:

```
int data = DateTime.Now.Year + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Day;
```

Однако этот код делает не то что нужно, он складывает эти числа, а мне надо получить вот такой результат: 2012510, я попробовал сделать так:

```
string data = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
```

Он выводит то что мне нужно, однако у меня в базе есть число такого вида: 201259 так вот мне надо от сегодняшнего числа отнять то что в базе(загнять данные в переменную я могу)

Comment: А форматированный выводне круто?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Может быть по этой ссылке вам поможет

Comment: Да нет, вы верно не поняли, мне надо просто загнать в переменную типа int дату без точек

Правильно: 2012510
Неправильно: 2012.5.10

Comment: А так

    int data = (DateTime.Now.Year*100 + DateTime.Now.Month)*100 + DateTime.Now.Day;

Comment: Ого, а что это за 100? У меня ошибка помпилятора. Я убрал 100 и получилось, тоже-самое что и просто сложение.

Comment: умножение там очевидно

Comment: Это была такая фича хэшкода. Результат сразу не посмотрел, некогда было

Comment: А какой результат должен получиться в результате вычитания?

Comment: Да, кстати, верный вопрос, учитывая, что даже формат числа будет разный (от 6значного до 8значного). 

Поэтому лучше использовать Format и а паттерн типа "{0:yyyyMMdd}"

Comment: Да - да, например, число 2012131 весьма не однозначно...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да вы сделайте как вы делали во втором случае

Только потом переведите в число

Или например

```
string data = String.Format("{0:yyyyMd}", dt); // думаю лучше String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", dt);
int dataInt = int.Parse(data);
```